# What I'm doing wrong when trying call back function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a call back function for this function in javascript

```
function Filtering_GetSite(siteElement) {

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "samle.asmx/f1",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (response) {

        var filtersitedetails = response.d;
        var appendItem = "";

        $(siteElement).empty();

        $.each(filtersitedetails, function (index, Filtering_GetSiteInfo) {

            var activeappend = "";
            var id = Filtering_GetSiteInfo.id;
            var site = Filtering_GetSiteInfo.site;

            activeappend = "<option value=" + id + ">" + site + "</option>";

            appendItem += activeappend;

        });

        $(siteElement).prepend('<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select Site</option>');
        $(siteElement).append(appendItem);

    },

    error: function (response) {
        alert("error in Filtering_GetSite");
    }
});
}
```

and this is how I call the function and trying to use call back function

```
Filtering_GetSite("#txt-site-name", function () {
           alert('ok')
           Dashboard_GetAgentInfo(agentParam,agentElement);
       });
```

but the problem is it doesn't go to the alert when the function is finished. How can I do this?

Comment: You didn't define a parameter for that callback in your function, so there's no way to reference it. `function Filtering_GetSite(siteElement, callbackFn) {`. So then in the function, you'd invoke it and pass whatever you want to it, where appropriate. `callbackFn(some_data)`

Comment: Um, `Filtering_GetSite` makes no reference to it's 2nd argument, and that's the callback functuon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wrap.

You need to specificy a second parameter for a callback function

I also added a condition so when you omit the second parameter it will check the `callback` if its a function or not so you can call the function just `Filtering_GetSite(sample)` insted of `Filtering_GetSite(sample,function(){})`

```
function Filtering_GetSite(siteElement, callback) {
 if (typeof (callBack) == "function") {
            callBack();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you do not seem to pass and invoke that method when the `ajax` invokes successfully.

First you will have to change the method signature of `Filtering_GetSite` to accept a 2nd parameter which in this case is the `callback` and then when the `ajax` is a success you just invoke it.

```
function Filtering_GetSite(siteElement, callback) {
   ...

   success: function() {
      ....

      callback();
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set your callback parameter into your `Filtering_GetSite` function. e.g.

```
function Filtering_GetSite(siteElement, callback) {
}
```

You can then call the callback with `callback()` where you want it to fire. For example within the `success` block;